# Typescript errors in `store.select()` after upgrading from ngrx@12 to 13

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

After I upgraded `ngrx` from v12 to v13 I'm getting such errors when using `store.select(selector)`

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: AppState) => Project[]): Observable<Project[]>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps<Object, unknown, Project[], DefaultProjectorFn<Project[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: AppState) => Project[]'.   Overload 2 of 9, '(key: keyof AppState): Observable<AuthState | CompanyContextState | CoreState | UIState | DepartmentState | TaskViewFiltersState | TaskViewFiltersStateMobile | { ...; } | ProjectViewFilters>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps<Object, unknown, Project[], DefaultProjectorFn<Project[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof AppState'.       Type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps<Object, unknown, Project[], DefaultProjectorFn<Project[]>>' is not assignable to type '"projectViewFilters"'.
```

My specific case is:

```
this.store.select(selectProjectsByCompany) // <- here errors
```

Selector definition

```
export const selectProjectsByCompany = createSelector(
  selectCompanyContext,
  getUser,
  projectSelectors.selectEntities,
  (
    { companyId }: CompanyContextState,
    currentUser: User,
    projects: Project[],
  ): Project[] => {
    if (currentUser) {
      if (currentUser.role === UserRole.SUPERADMIN) {
        return projects.filter(
          (project: Project) => project.companyId === companyId,
        );
      } else {
        return projects.filter(
          (project: Project) => project.companyId === currentUser.companyId,
        );
      }
    }
    return [];
  },
);
```

2 slice selectors

```
export const selectCompanyContext = (state: AppState): CompanyContextState =>
  state.companyContext;
```

```
export const getUser = createSelector(
  authObj,
  (state: AuthState) => state.user,
);
```

And the typing for `AuthState`.

```
export class AuthState {
  permissions: string[];
  expires: number;
  user: any;
  username: string;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  token: string;
  refreshToken: string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It came out that typings should be inferred from `AuthState`.
A selector `getUser` supposed to return `User` type. Because typings is not explicitly declared in case of `AuthState.user` it couldn't be inferred.

State typings should be carefully and explicitly declared to not to rely on workarounds like:
`createSelector<AppState, [CompanyContextState, User, Project[]], Project[]>`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with your feature (reducer) selector that on upgrade has to be changed from something like:

```js
export const selectYourReducer = (state) => state[reducerKeys.yourKey];
```

to something like:

```js
export const selectYourReducer = createFeatureSelector(reducerKeys.yourKey) as YourReducerState;
```